# An weak type sobolev multiplication theorem

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Suppose that $f_i\rightharpoonup f$ in $W^{1,p}$ and $g_i\rightharpoonup g$ in $W^{1,q}$ with $q=\frac{np}{n-p}$, what the best $r$, for which we have $f_ig_i\rightharpoonup fg$ in $L^r$ (maybe $W^{1,r}$)?

Comment: See also my related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563377/weak-convergence-and-strong-convergence

Comment: Are you working in bounded domains?

Comment: @Tomás At first, you can add a lot of good conditions to work it out! Then we can try together to generalize it.