# Compactness of Sobolev Space in L infinity

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, sobolev-spaces, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

I want to show that if $u_{m} \rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ then $u_{m} \rightarrow u$ in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

I know that I can't directly use the compactness of Rellich Kondrachov Theorem since I am taking $p = \infty$. From Morrey's Inequality I have $||u||_{C^{0,\alpha}} \leq ||u||_{W^{1,p}}$ where $\alpha = 1 - \frac{n}{p}$. Is it possible to take this further and show that $W^{1,p}(\Omega) \Subset L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is $C^{1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a direct proof for $L^\infty$,  without Hölder spaces or Morrey inequality.

1. By the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem, every infinite bounded subset of $W^{1,\infty}$ has a limit point in $L^\infty$.
2. Therefore, the embedding of $W^{1,\infty}$ into $L^\infty$ is compact.
3. A compact operator [maps weakly convergent sequences into convergent sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/564447/127096).

---

*Old answer*: Every $C^1$ domain, and more generally    a Lipschitz domain, is a *Sobolev extension domain*, meaning that Sobolev functions on it can be extended to Sobolev functions on $\mathbb R^n$. In particular, all embedding theorems for Sobolev spaces hold on such domains.

When $p>n$, Morrey's inequality gives a continuous embedding of $W^{1,p}$ into $C^\beta$ with $\beta=1-n/p$. In turn, $C^\beta$ compactly embeds into $C^\alpha$ for $0<\alpha<\beta$. See [Is there a reference for compact imbedding of Hölder space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/450028/) This topic was also discussed in [Compact, continuous embeddings of $H^s := W^{s,2} \leftrightarrow C^{(\alpha)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/461227/) (in one dimension).

Under your assumptions, you can get $u_m\to u$ in any space $C^\alpha$ with $\alpha\in (0,1)$. *A fortiori*, $u_m\to u$ in $L^\infty$.

Comment: How do I get $u_{m} \rightarrow u$ in $C^{\alpha}$? I showed continuous embedding which it seems would only imply $u_{m} \rightharpoonup u$ in $C^{\alpha}$, since I only assume $u_{m} \rightharpoonup u$ in $W^{1,p}$.

Comment: @John The continuous embedding is followed by a compact one.

Comment: Okay so basically $W^{1,\infty} \subset C^{\alpha} \Subset L^{\infty}$?

Comment: @John Yes, with the second embedding being compact.

Comment: When I do the working and use Arzela Ascoli as you state I can show that given the weakly convergent sequence $\{ u_{m} \}_{m}$ in $W^{1,\infty}$ there is a subsequence ${u_{m_{j}}}_{j}$ which converges uniformly in $C(\Omega)$, does this then imply that  $u_{m_{j}}$ converges strongly in $L^{\infty}$?

Comment: Does this follow since $L^{\infty}$ convergence is uniform convergence a.e.?

Comment: @JohnDoe I added a proof to the top of the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you look at my proof using Morrey's inequality and Holder spaces? I will post as a question.

Comment: The post is called 'Sobolev, Holder, Lp spaces continous and compact embeddings proof'.